# Custom JAX-RS JSON @Provider

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I have one issue with defining custom JAX-RS @Provider. I can successfully use GSON through this my custom @Provider but only for subclasses of my Base class. Something like this

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonEntityProvider<T extends Base> implements MessageBodyReader<T>, MessageBodyWriter<T> {...}
```

If I have Collection it doesn't go through this custom provider but uses the container-provided one. I tried to do Object instead of the T and expected that all Objects go through this provider, but in that case it doesn't work for anything at all (The container-provided one is used instead). One way that I could make it work is to create another @Provider that is

```
<T extends Collection>
```

But this is not elegant because I might consider converting Maps too. I would not like to add @Provider for everything that my REST endpoints consume/produce.

The provided JAXB (Moxy) within glassfish is not producing the results I expect, so I want to use my custom JSON entity provider using GSON for the un/marshaling.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just JsonEntityProvider<T> in which case, the type is known inside the `readFrom(Class<T>...` methods.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that... I already tried that too.. Also tried to skip using generics but just do plain implementation of the interfaces. I get the same issue. I might try using different container. Currently trying to work it out with embedded-glassfish (glassfish 4).